What is being omitted in this sentence/what is the structure?

大洋は敢えて相貌に剣呑な、そして威圧的な気配を滲ませた。それだけで覚束ない人間であれば気後れする。

I fundamentally understand it's saying the character makes himself look scary and lets out a overbearing presence. So if the adversary is someone doubtful, he will lose his nerves.
But what 相貌に剣呑な here? I can't quite make sense of it.

に marks 相貌 as the "target" or "destination" of 滲ませる. The comma after 剣呑な may be throwing you off, but 剣呑な、そして威圧的な just means "dangerous and intimidating", two parallel adjectives which describe 気配. So 相貌に剣呑な気配を滲ませた means something like "let a sense of danger creep into one's expression", and に corresponds to "into".
